# Construct 4 x 4 magic square with fixed location for “1”

Tags: algorithm, numbers, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, magic-square

The [method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square#A_method_of_constructing_a_magic_square_of_doubly_even_order) I have found to generate 4 by 4 magic squares gives me a result in which the number "1" is at of the corners of the square. How can we extend this to a method to generate a magic square, for a fixed location of number "1"?

The number "1" can be in 16 different locations (cells). If we name the cells, from upper left corner: 1, 2, 3,4, 5, ..., and the number "1" is at the $i^th$ cell, then how we can fill the other cells to make a magic square?

Comment: 4x4 isn't that much to brute-force. The number 1 is fixed, so only 15 free cells. After every three cells the fourth is fixed. After three rows the fourth row is fixed. Only 8 values to choose, really.

Comment: Since new magic squares can be (trivially) generated from existing ones by reflection and rotation there are really only 4 interesting locations for the placement of the `1`.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I Assume you mean 3 locations?

Comment: No, I mean 4.  Place the 1 in any of the 4 cells in one quadrant of the 4x4 magic square, all the others are rotations and reflections.  But I could be wrong.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Surely positions [1,2] and [2,1] are mirrored? They are both sides, with the other two options being corner and center.